# Why is my property inaccessible for a class in different folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2

I'm noticing something really strange.

I have a class A with a property:

```
 @interface ClassA
 @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;
```

and a synthesize in the .m file.

now if I have a second class B as following:

```
 #import "ClassA.h"

 -(void) someMethod
 {
      ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
      classA.test = @"test";
 }
```

than this works fine if the 2 class files are in the same folder.

If I however move the files to separate subfolders, it won't work anymore.
The error I get is that the property doesn't exist. Similarly, 'intellisense' won't show the test property anymore.

If I make folder groups in xcode, but leave the actual files in the same physical folder, it does work.

Whats going on here?

It can't be an include path problem, since then I wouldn't even be able to instantiate ClassA.

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project and then building?

Comment: You should be able to do this, that is very strange behavior. Have you tried ctrl + space inside empty ""in import ?

Comment: I tried both cleaning, restarting xcode, and tapping ctrl-space. It won't show the property. If I subclass the class, I do see the properties from the subclass. Very strange.

Comment: Generate the preprocessed file of ClassB (Product -> Generate Output -> Preprocessed file in Xcode 4) to see if the correct ClassA.h is being imported.

Comment: Does the problem only occur when you move a class, or does it also occur when classes are initially created in different folders?

Comment: I just tried to create fresh class in the subfolder...and now it works. So it definitely seems like it has to do with moving files around.

Comment: @JeremyP: Your idea with the preprocessed output made it visible that the incorrect class was imported. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

already tried Xcode menu "product:clean"?

and i would try to delete your app from simulator, and also Xcode:preferences:locations:derived data -> from finder delete that finder folder

Answer (score 1):

Try `COMMAND+SHIFT+K` and
Reset content and settings in iOS Simulator.

Did you try @class ClassA?

Comment: cleaning the solution doesn't solve it. Resetting the simulator has nothing to do with the compiler. Adding @class is only beneficial in .h files if you don't want to impor the class definition yet.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had an included subproject which used a class with the exact same name.
aaaaargh...

apparently there are no errors during compilation and it's unclear which of the files it will import.